# "Something is off"

Tags: idioms

In this paragraph, does "something is off" mean "something is not right", "something is different" or something else?

> There was definitely something off about Mr. Bittner today, she
>   thought.  It wasn’t just the way he paused at certain points in his
>   lecture to look at her.  Teachers  were always doing that, the good
>   ones, anyway—scanning their classrooms during their lectures. 
>   But every time  Bittner paused—every time—his eyes stopped upon her.

Thanks!

Comment: I think it means that there is definitely something strange or unusual today or he isn't himself today.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something unusual, not quite right. He was acting a bit unlike himself.